# Phonegap plugins behaving strangely

Tags: cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins

I have multiple plugins in a phone gap app: social share (nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing) and an in-app-browser (org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser).

I'm not sure I can describe what's happening here technically, but the behavior I'm seeing on an iPad is:

I tap the trigger for either plugin and nothing happens.

I double tap the iPad home button, showing the showing the fast app switcher, and up comes the plugin.

If I go back into the app everything works smoothly.

Quit and re-launch and it's broken again.

Has anyone seen this behavior? I can't even guess as to what's going on here...

Comment: Maybe not waiting for `deviceready` event to fire before trying to use plugins?

Comment: I hadn't though of that... but no the plugins are triggered by user touches well after the app has launched and the deviceready event has fired.